# How do I hack into Promise Array Management?

Tags: password-recovery, raid

One of our servers, which was installed long before my time at the company began, has two Promise Raid cards installed.  It also has Promise Array Management version  3.0.0.36 (9/17/2002) installed.  I am unable to log into the utility.  There is no record of passwords.  According to the manual, the password is set up during installation.

Is there a way to find out what the password is, or change it?  Alternatively, can I uninstall the utility and reinstall it?  Will that allow me to recreate the password?

Comment: Uninstalling the utility worked.  On re-installation, the utility creates a new user database and prompts for the administrator password.

Comment: Feel free to post & accept your answer, I'm sure someone else will need this someday!

Comment: We reinstalled WebPam and found that admin/admin worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling the utility worked. On re-installation, the utility creates a new user database and prompts for the administrator password.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a stale question but I have come across a few versions of the PAM software that didnt prompt during install and had a default of admin/admin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default usernames and passwords? Username of 'admin' or 'administrator' and password 'administrator' or 'password'.

Comment: Those did not work.  The install has a screen which sets the administrator password. Defaults are not applicable.

Comment: Really?  I guess I must have been thinking of another raid card then.